Issues running Fama French regression for annual portfolios
As part of my master thesis I am planning to do some analysis based on the 3-Factor Fama french model. I am not a quantitative finance person at all, so my question might be extremely basic and I might be missing something very basic.
My idea is, I have the list of companies from 2000-2023. For each year, I want to sort the companies into quartiles (top 25%, mid 25%, mid 25% and bottom 25%) based on their ROICs. These quartiles would be 1 portfolio. Which means the year 2000 will have 4 portfolios of random companies (which may or may not be repeated) the year 2001 will also have 4 portfolios of random companies. I want to then regress the excess returns of these companies within a portfolio (1 year company return - Riskfree rate) against the 3 factors of Fama-French. So, there should be ideally 4 regression equations for each year for each quartile. One equation for Quartile 1 in 2000, one equation for Quartile 2 in 2000, so on and so forth.
The problem I am facing is, whenever I run the regression, my coefficients for the 3 factors are returned as NA since my SMB, HML value from the dartmouth website are the same for each company as I am using annual SMB, HML values. So for eg, for Quartile 1 of the year 2000, the company based excess returns are different but the SMB and HML values are the same for each company, leading to an NA return and the r-code says that there are singularities, which I really do not understand.
Can anyone suggest another approach, help me out with the code, or tell me where the problem is? I am genuinely struggling with this. Any help is appreciated. I have a serious concern that what I am trying to do is actually not possible hence I would appreciate all the help
Thank you!

What subject-matter question are you trying to answer with your empirical analysis?

I suppose you are performing cross-sectional regressions? Are you trying to identify how exposed certain tiers of ROIC firms are related to the FF3 factors?

@RichardHardy my Idea is to first sort them based on ROICs and create 4 portfolios and then run a regression against the FF3 factors. The idea is that if the intercept is high, we can conclude that ROIC does help predicting excess returns. But when I ran the regression - the problem that I am now facing is that my multiple R-squared is too low.

You are still focused on the methods. Could you address my question directly?
